# Questions about fileContentReplaceItemConfig search pattern using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following groovy instructions applied on Jenkins.

```
stage('Replace content') {
  steps {
    contentReplace(
     configs: [
        fileContentReplaceConfig(
              configs: [
                 fileContentReplaceItemConfig(
                       search: ".appName.*",
                       replace: ''
                 )
              ],
         fileEncoding: 'UTF-8',
         filePath: 'register.scala')
     ])
  }
}
```

What is the meaning of the pattern ".appName.*"? Every line which contains the word 'appName', the entire line will be removed in register.scala file?

Comment: It's a regular expression.  It's not necessarily the entire line.  Here is an example string: asdfasdfappNameasdf  this would be replaced with asdfasd.  So it will replace appName, a character before appName, and everything after appName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Content Replace plugin

The [Content Replace](https://plugins.jenkins.io/content-replace/) plugin site states the following

> Regex expression for search. e.g. (Version=)([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)

It is a regular expression. It's not necessarily the entire line. Here is an example string: `asdfasdfappNameasdf` this would be replaced with `asdfasd`. So it will replace appName, a character before appName, and everything after appName

Below is a pattern matching example from [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

[image: regex]